# Canvas allows 760px, my website is 900px width. What should I do?

Tags: php, facebook

My website is 900px witdth. Is there anything I can do that through facebook canvas my website would look better? Or I absolutely need to rechange my template? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to use a flexible layout or rebuild it.  It's that simple.